# Regex, matcher, and DateTimeParseException: Text '01/08/2018' could not be parsed at index 0

Tags: java, java-8, date-parsing, localdate

I am getting this issue `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '01/08/2018' could not be parsed at index 0` from this code below.  Not sure what other options I have to parse a string by using this matcher.

```
    String dateString = "At 01/08/2018"
    String regex = "At (\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4})";
    Matcher mDate = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(dateString);
    if (mDate.find()) {
        DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
                .appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 2)
                .toFormatter();
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(mDate.group(1), fmt);
        order.setDate(asDate(localDate)); 
    } else {
        // fails..
    }
}

public static Date asDate(LocalDate localDate) {
    return Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
}
```

The output for example: `2018-01-08T00:00:07` but the tricky part here is dateString doesn't have that time set up so maybe the DateTimeFormatterBuilder might work plus setting the `order.setDate` is a Date type.

Comment: your `mDate.group(1)` returns value in dd/MM/yyyy format but yyyyMMddHHmmss pattern is given to DateTimeFormatter. It clearly shows it failed to parse at index 0 means here year (yyyy). Also there is no time information in your input and order of date fields are wrong.

Comment: thank you i fixed it and yes didn't know i needed to add hours and minutes but the asDate did that trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need both a regular expression *and* a `DateTimeFormatter` for checking whether your string format agrees with the expected. You *do* need the formatter to match the expected input.

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("'At 'MM/dd/uuuu");
    String dateString = "At 01/08/2018";
    try {
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(dateString, dateFormatter);
        System.out.println(localDate);
        // order.setDate(asDate(localDate));
    } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
        // fails..
    }
```

This prints

```
2018-01-08
```

I believe you intended Jan 8; if you intended 1 Aug, swap `MM` and `dd` in the format pattern string.

PS Your `asDate` can be implemented slightly more simply, clearly and correctly:

```
    return Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

Comment: thank you yes swapped it! and better clean up with that return.